# Piface with Scratch. Could not find MESH session

Tags: setup, peripherals, scratch

I've downloaded and installed the latest versions of everything. Followed the instructions for setting up Scratch to use Mesh. It says its using IP 127.0.1.1.
From the terminal I ran 'pifacedigital-scratch-handler'. It said could not find MESH session at 127.0.0.1:42001. So I ran 'pifacedigital-scratch-handler 127.0.1.1'. It said could not find MESH session at 127.0.1.1:42001.
I'm brand new to the Pi, so all new to me. Any ideas please.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what I did different today but works. The mesh auto starts when starting scratch. Stopped and restarted then ran pifacedigital-scratch-handler 127.0.1.1
All working.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem! If you solved the problem on your own, please mark this answer as answer. Yes, it can be done on your own answer and will help get the site stats up. Thanks!